# Deleting sent messages in UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

Let me elaborate a little bit more for example if I have this code:

This object is created by the main UI thread:

```
Handler handler= new Handler();
```

Then I use:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
}, 1000);
```

My question is, can I cancel that action so that if posted to the main thread's message queue?

Comment: You could use the removeCallback methods.

Comment: on the same handler object?

Comment: Also how can I identify the runnables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove previously posted Runnables using the [removeCallbacks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) method on the Handler used to post them.  You will need to have the *exact* reference to the Runnable posted.

In your code, you post a Runnable while declaring it anonymously inline.  If you do that, won't retain a reference to that Runnable.  Instead, you can store the reference to that new Runnable in a member variable or something that won't be forgotten by the time you want to remove it.

```
private Runnable r;  // assign before use
private Handler h;   // assign before use

private void schedule() {
    h.postDelayed(r, 99999);
}

private void cancel() {
    h.removeCallbacks(r);
}
```